# How would I write in mathematical notation an integer greater than 1?

Tags: notation

I have written $a \in \mathbb{Z} > 1$ (note: I've written the Z in proper integer form; I just need to write this question quickly)

Comment: I think $a>1$ with $a\in \Bbb Z$ is better. The notation $\Bbb Z_{>1}$ is not very popular, and $\Bbb Z>1$ is not used at all.

Comment: Use more words. That's no less "mathematical" and easier for your reader.

Comment: Either your notation or any of the two in the prior comment or a myriad of others will work. Mathematicians never agree on how to write this anyhow

Comment: How about $\{n \in \mathbb Z \mid n>1\}$ ?

Comment: Mathematicians are lazy , but this should not be exaggerated. Writing "integer $n>1$" should not bother even the laziest mathematician.

Comment: The reason I am trying is this is for a group project and my lecturer said to use as much mathematical notation as possible and not make it wordy.

Comment: He meant this for the whole project and not for $a>1$. This has enough notation.

Comment: How about $\mathbb Z\cap (1,\infty)$?

Comment: _"my lecturer said to use as much mathematical notation as possible and not make it wordy"_ **(1)** Use the notation your lecturer uses; he/she might not like notation they are not used to. **(2)** Use notation from recommended reading for your course. It is likely you use your lecture slides as your primary (or only) source. I strongly recommend going to the library and checking out the table of contents of each book in your reading list. Some books have a separate notation table.

Comment: $x \in \Bbb{Z_{> 1}}~$ or $~x \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}}.~~$ Irrelevant whether such usage is widespread.  Usage is clear and unambiguous.  It will be impossible for the reader to be in any way confused what you are trying to communicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, we use $\mathbb{Z}^+$ for the set of positive integers and $\mathbb{N}$ for the set of non-negative integers. So $\mathbb{N} = \mathbb{Z}^+ \cup \{0\}$.

In your case, you can use $a \in \{n \in \mathbb{Z} | n > 1\}$ if you need the general set, but otherwise, just $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $a > 1$ should do. Another way is $a \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \backslash \{1\}$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde sorry published too soon

Comment: No problem.....